# I cant find my spouse

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After the wedding ceremony in Riften, before my wife left, I asked her where we should live. After I told her, me and her left and I can't find her at the house, OR at the Temple of Mara. Where can I find her?

Comment: Let's keep this open, solely on the basis of having a great name.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not how the system works.